# Tag specific information required?

Tags: feature-request

One of the standard things that comes up a lot in the `perl` questions, is to:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Because it turns on a load of things that are optional, but good practice (and in so doing, weeds out a lot of the more inane errors that you can get with `perl`).

I'm also pretty sure that there are quite a few 'common errors' or 'commonly required information' that are going to be inherently tag specific.

And perhaps you've got tags that are worth a reminder when being used together (I recall recent discussions on `C` vs. `C++` or `java` and `javascript` for example.).

That's especially true if a tag is very specific, such as referencing a particular library, server, module etc.

I suppose I'm sort of suggesting a FAQ reference for posters based on tags.

Is this something that would be useful?

Answer (score 1):

What you're suggesting is effectively to add tutorials/FAQs/best practice information on all languages (and other IT fields) in existence (starting from the major ones).

[It's out of its scope, I'm afraid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic). Such information is bound to get inaccurate and/or outdated, if not incite edit wars since best practices are field-specific.

The current state of affairs appears to [try to maintain good "overview" answers on specific topics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276332/the-1-so-question-about-python-ides-is-very-out-of-date). Another live example is [the FAQ/best practice reference on SO/SE itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). These still suffer from the problem outlines in the previous paragraph.

UPDATE: the narrower version of your suggestion, reformulated in a field-agnostic way, is something like *"Make sure you know and heed the best practices in the language/field you're asking about. This will lower the probability that your problem is a simple oversight."* In this form, it can be discussed to be added in ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (as elaboration to "search and research") or a banner above the edit window.

Comment: I was thinking more a per tag 'how to ask' rather than anything exhaustive.

Comment: "How to ask" is still within the domain of a FAQ.

Comment: But we do include it in the help for the site, because by doing so we promote good questions.

Comment: The "how to ask in general" in within the scope of the (meta) site since it's directly related to the (main) site's processes. "How to ask on a specific field" is out of scope since the site isn't field-specific.

Answer (score 1):

This information can be added to the tag wiki, and often is. For example, the wiki for Perl can be found here (or by clicking "learn more..." that appears close to the top of the page when  at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/ )

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info

In some tag wikis, information on related tags or useful websites for writing questions are given, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info contains information on how to tag and this statement:

> You should always provide complete code examples (e.g. schema, data sample and expected result) in your question or answer, but you can also isolate problematic code and reproduce it in an online environment such as SQL Fiddle.