# Common Google Search for Node.js / JavaScript IDE leads to out of date Stack Overflow question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, vote-to-delete

If you Google for "node js ide / editor" or "javascript ide / editor" the answer [IDE for Node.js / JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919977/ide-for-node-js-javascript) ranks near the top of the results. The answer is out of date (going on four years).

The question has been locked leading visitors to be misinformed. Are there any options here?

From related questions:

1. Can we put a banner on the top of the question stating it is out of date?
2. Can we delete the question?
3. Can we open it and put an answer with content that can be updated over time? See the top answer to [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python). (Personally I'm not a fan of this as it seems hard to keep up.)

Disclaimer - I work on VS Code. I would like to see VS Code and Atom in the answer as viable solutions.

Related questions

- [The number one Stack Overflow question about Python IDEs is very out of date](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276332/the-number-one-stack-overflow-question-about-python-ides-is-very-out-of-date)

Comment: It's only still up due to historical significance but if it's no longer useful, deletion should be an option. You'd have to convince folks it's not worth keeping around though.

Comment: And this is why those questions are off topic.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Let's delete.

This is completely off-topic (tool recommendation) and outdated now. The only valid option I see here is to ask mods to delete the question.

Comment: Doesnt deleting affect reputation ??

Comment: Agreed - and done.

Comment: @ModarNa Only recent reputation gains, as far as I remember.

Comment: @ModarNa if you get score =>3 and the post is kept for 60 days, you don't lose reputation. Only if the post score doesn't reach 3 or 60 days everything is lost.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @Braiam

Comment: Where should people who sincerely want to get advice about tool use (including IDE recommendations) ask their questions?

Comment: @mrts not here.

Comment: @mrts [softwarerecs.SE] would be a good start